# CSS positioning breaks in Safari

Tags: css, html, webkit, css-position

i have a website in which i am trying to position (using CSS) a certain  on the page. the  is absolutely positioned and is located inside a relatively positioned paernt .
on firefox and even IE it looks ok but on Safari, things get messy and it shows 5 pixels lower than it should. i have tried to figure out for days now what is wrong there but cannot seem to see it.

you can find an example link to the problematic page here: 
http://yaronattar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=117:the-new-lovers-2010&catid=51:the-new-lovers-2010&Itemid=242

the problematic  is the one conaining the "previous/next" navigation at the bottom right corner of the page.

anyone sees what is causing the trouble here?

thanks

Comment: I wouldn't call that "positioning using CSS": your page's full of tables.

Comment: can you break this out into a smaller well contained example?

Comment: I think you must have linked to the wrong thing. There's no CSS positioning applied to the previous/next links, they're just wedged into a tiny table.

Comment: Can you put backticks around your tags, like `<this>`, so we can see them? Now they're eaten by this site. And it's a WebKit problem, not a Safari-only issue, as it also pops up in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This will target webkit browsers only (Chrome, Safari and I think a version of Opera too)

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    /Chrome and Safari CSS here/

    #id-name {
        position:absolute;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        left:100px;
        bottom:100px;
    }
    }
```

Comment: thanks to all of you.
the page was full of automatically generated tables. i removed them and used DIV tags instead and now all is nice and looks the same everyewhere. thanks.